# ExtJS - Issue with Selecting First Cell for Editing in Newly Created Grid Row for Rapid Multi-Row Data Entry

Tags: extjs

The key requirement for this project I am working on is the ability to rapidly enter hundreds of rows of data at a time by pressing return/enter while editing a cell in an ExtJS grid and then having a new row created with the first editable cell highlighted so the user can basically fast-type hundreds of rows without having to look at the keyboard. I have the code working, but the only way I could get it to work is by using a deferred javascript call, and I think that is not ideal.

When the user hits return/enter in a cell, I create a new dummy record and insert it into the store. In the store's "add" event, I then try to highlight the first cell in the new row created for this new record in the store. But this only works if I use a deferred call to the startEditByPosition method. If I call the method directly, it doesn't work. I tried the "add" and "added" event on the grid and grid view, but they don't seem to fire when I new row is added to the grid.

I'd like to know when the grid row is "ready" to received a startEdit command rather than trying to do this in the add event for the store because it seems that is too early to do so.

The fact that a deferred call of 0 vs 1ms is the difference between the startEditByPosition command not working vs working makes me pretty sure that the UI isn't ready even though the store is.

```
{
    header: "Part #",
    dataIndex: "part_number",
    width: 100,
    editor:
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        selectOnFocus:true,
        listeners:
        {
            specialkey: function(field, e)
            {
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER)
                {
                    var view = this.up("viewport").lineItemGrid.getView(),
                    rec = new AAW.ItemModel({
                    sort_order: 100000,
                });

                var count=view.store.getCount();

                view.store.insert(view.store.getCount(), rec);
            }
        },
    }
},

Ext.define("AAW.ItemStore",
{
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "AAW.ItemModel",
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    sorters:{property: "sort_order", direction: 'ASC'},
    listeners:
    {
        add:function(a,b,c,d,e,f)
        {
            //a.deferFocus(a.getCount()-1);
            //Ext.Function.defer(a.deferFocus, 0, this, [a.getCount()-1]);
            Ext.Function.defer(a.deferFocus, 1, this, [a.getCount()-1]);
        },
    },
    deferFocus:function(row)
    {
        this.parentAppReference.lineItemGrid.findPlugin('cellediting').startEditByPosition({row: row, column: 5});
    }
}
```